# Is there any way to sync my Visual Studio Code settings between instances?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'd like to be able to sync my VS Code user settings (File > Preferences > User Settings) to the cloud somehow so I can easily share them between multiple installations, as in Windows 10 and Visual Studio.

Is there a supported way of doing this? Direct support in Code would be great, but otherwise being able to move my settings.json location to a Dropbox or OneDrive folder would work too.

I'm looking specifically for a way of doing this automatically and silently. Manually exporting/importing is too cumbersome and isn't what I'm looking for.

---

**Update:** this is now a [built-in feature in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync).

Comment: A very simple way would be if you use Google's Backup and Sync program and just add to backup your C:\Users\\[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export settings of Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368889/how-to-export-settings-of-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is finally a built-in feature: see [Settings Sync in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync).

Comment: Still in preview though

Comment: @FrankFu Well, but this is a big feature, and they're making progress: you're able to sync to microsoft/github account, and there's a proposed api for account login etc. (which will be useful to other extensions such us github btw)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, oh 100%, in no way was my intention to complain. I felt like it needed to be cleared up to avoid giving people false hope since the original unedited answer did not say otherwise.

Comment: In 1.48 it is stable now: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_48.md#settings-sync

Answer (score 136):

**Note:** The answer below is about a deprecated extension. Other answers point out the existence of alternatives, the most common one being the built-in one.

I have developed an extension that will sync all your Visual Studio Code Settings across multiple instances.

**Key Features**

1. Use your GitHub account token.
2. Easy to Upload and Download on one click.
3. Saves all settings and snippets files.
4. Upload Key : Shift + Alt + u
5. Download Key : Shift + Alt + d
6. Type Sync In Order to View all sync options

**It Sync**

- Settings File
- Keybinding File
- Launch File
- Snippets Folder
- VSCode **Extensions**

**Detail Documentation Source**

[VSCode - Settings Sync blog post](http://shanalikhan.github.io/2015/12/15/Visual-Studio-Code-Sync-Settings.html)

**Download here : [VS Code - Settings Sync - Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)**

Comment: Thanks Shan Khan - this extension is quite useful - I have a set of virtual servers where I need to sync VS Code settings and key bindings between instances and this extension works exactly as advertised.

Comment: Tried it but no success.  When I activate it by Alt-Shift U, I get an error:
extensionHost.ts:293[Extension Host] {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}A.logExtensionHostMessage @ extensionHost.ts:293
messageService.ts:126Error Logged In Console (Help menu > Toggle Developer Tools). You may open an issue using 'Sync : Open Issue' from advance setting command.e.doShow @ messageService.ts:126

Comment: because the token is not valid, try resetting the extension settings and add new generated token

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer, but I tried the tool out and found it unreliable and buggy. Very simple scenario: VS Code installed on two machines, and I was trying to get both to auto-upload/download settings and extensions changes. I eventually gave up after failing to get it to work. So, great idea but needs more work.

Comment: @MarkWhitaker u can post an issue in github with the exception its giving so we can discuss it further.

Comment: There was no exception, it just didn't work. I'd change settings in one instance, close it down, open another instance: nothing synced.

Comment: @MarkWhitaker Indeed. I tried just today and rather than syncing and merging my extensions / settings between two environments, it overwrote all of the above from the initial environment where I first installed the extension and forced the identical state into my other environments. It does not appear to be a proper syncing tool which actually merges differences and tries to reconcile them. The states should be merged, and where a conflict exists, the user should be prompted to address it. :(

Comment: I have mixed feelings posting my settings to a (semi-)public Gist. Some extensions store sensitive data (such as database logins, SFTP logins) in their settings. Would it be hard to redirect storage to a "local" file instead, synchronized by an external tool like Syncthing or Resilio Sync?

Comment: @korkman for handling these situations, Settings Sync will allow to sync via local files and git repositories like gist in future updates.

Comment: I totally agree with @korkman -- Shan Khan, is there likely to be any movement on this any time soon?

Comment: Is there anyway to run this from a CLI?

Answer (score 21):

You can make a hard link from the directory containing user settings to your sync directory of applications such as Dropbox or OneDrive.

For example, on windows, the user settings are located in `%APPDATA%\Code\User`, so you could type:

`mklink /H /J X:\Your\Sync\Dir %APPDATA%\Code\User`

on your computers with Visual Studio Code to achieve the synchronization.

Then, on another computer, you may delete the `%APPDATA%\Code\User` folder, and type:

`mklink /H /J %APPDATA%\Code\User X:\Your\Sync\Dir`

to retrieve the synchronized settings.

Comment: Hi ! I don't understand why you would need to make a link FROM the sync directory TO the %appdata% folder. Move once for all your actual VS settings in the sync directory (DropBox, OneDrive, whatever...), then on every computer you want to sync the settings, delete `%APPDATA%\Code\User` and create the link by using `mklink /H /J %APPDATA%\Code\User X:\Your\Sync\Dir`

Comment: Because you will fail to create a link if the given name already exists, while the sync directory will be there once the settings have been downloaded.

Comment: This fails for network drives with the message `"Local NTFS volumes are required to complete the operation."`

Answer (score 13):

In v1.48:

> ### Preview features
>
> Preview features are not ready for release but are functional enough
> to use. We welcome your early feedback while they are under
> development.
>
> #### Settings Sync
>
> Settings Sync is now available for preview in the stable release .
> Refer to the [user guide](https://aka.ms/vscode-settings-sync-help)
> for more information & FAQs.
>
> Feature is now called **Settings Sync** also in the product. All of
> its references & settings are renamed to be aligned.

Also see "Manual merge" and syncing between Insiders and Stable at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_48.md#settings-sync

---

In v1.45 it looks like you will be able to login to the built-in Settings Sync via github, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95160#event-3266867554 (Support GitHub logins in settings sync).  And the [v1.45 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#settings-sync).

---

In v1.43 as a preview feature (so in the Insiders' Build only) is ***settings sync***. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#settings-sync

> **Settings Sync**

We have been working the last couple of months to support synchronizing VS Code settings, extensions, and keyboard shortcuts across machines (popular feature request [#2743](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2743)). In this milestone, we are happy to announce that this feature is ready for preview from our next [1.44.0-insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) release. You can now have your customizations synchronized in all your VS Code installs across all your machines. You can also bootstrap VS Code with your personal customizations on a fresh machine with minimal effort. Following video demonstrates this:

> Supports detecting conflicts in settings and keybindings while
> synchronizing. Conflicts are shown using the diff editor with incoming
> (cloud) changes on the left side and local changes on the right side.
> You can resolve the conflicts by editing in the right side editor and
> merge the changes using the actions provided in the editor.

**Supported Features**

> Currently Settings, Keyboard Shortcuts, Extensions, and the Display
> Language are synchronized but we are planning to add more. You can
> review our list of proposed [Setting Sync
> features](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Asettings-sync+label%3Afeature-request).
>
> Machine settings (with machine or machine-overridable scopes) are not
> synchronized by default. You can also add or remove settings you want
> to this list from settings editor or using the setting
> `sync.ignoredSettings`.
>
> Keyboard Shortcuts are synchronized per platform by default. If your
> keyboard shortcuts are platform agnostic then, you can synchronize
> them across platforms by disabling the setting
> `sync.keybindingsPerPlatform`.
>
> All built-in and installed extensions are synchronized along with
> their global enablement state. You can skip synchronizing an
> extension, from extensions view or using the setting
> `sync.ignoredExtensions`.
>
> Settings Sync activity can be monitored in the **Log (Sync)** output
> view. All local customizations are backed up for last 30 days (atleast
> 10) in the disk whenever they are changed during synchronization. You
> can use the command **Sync: Open Local Backups Folder** to go the
> backups location and retain your old customizations.

(and a few gifs at the release note link)

Note that is working **through your Microsoft account**, not github (until v1.45 - see top):

> Settings Sync uses a Microsoft account to store your VS Code customizations for synchronization and therefore you would need an
> account to use this. Refer to the [Settings Sync
> documentation](https://aka.ms/vscode-settings-sync-help) for more
> information and help.

Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/settings-sync.md for more on how to set up `settings sync`.

---

And a link to v1.44 info on Settings Sync: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#settings-sync

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll be keen to try this when it arrives.

Comment: The million dollar question is when will this hit stable. 1.46 is out but still insiders-only :(

Comment: @bviktor in 1.48 it is stable now: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_48.md#settings-sync

Answer (score 11):

Aha, you can try my VSCode extension: [Syncing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nonoroazoro.syncing).

Hoping you'll like it. :)

---

#### A Quick Guide

1. Install [Syncing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nonoroazoro.syncing):
2. Get your own `GitHub Personal Access Token`:

   1. **Login to your [GitHub](https://github.com) `Settings` page.**

      [image: login to settings page]
   2. **Select `Personal access tokens` tab and click `Generate new token`.**

      [image: generate new token]
   3. **Select `gist` and click `Generate token`.**

      [image: allow gist]
   4. **Copy and backup your token.**

      [image: copy and backup token]
3. Sync your settings:

   *`Syncing`* will ask for necessary information `for the first time` and `save for later use`.

   1. **Upload**:

      1. Type `upload` in `VSCode Command Palette`.
      2. Enter your `GitHub Personal Access Token`.
      3. Enter your `Gist ID` (or `leave it blank` to create automatically).
      4. Done!
      5. After uploading, you can find your settings and the corresponding `Gist ID` in your [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com).

         [image: settings and gist]
   2. **Download**:

      1. Type `download` in `VSCode Command Palette`.
      2. Enter your `GitHub Personal Access Token` (or `leave it blank` if you want to download from a public Gist)
      3. Enter your `Gist ID` (or a `public Gist ID`).
      4. Done!

Comment: Hm. This doesn't seem to sync the extensions I have installed in the reference VS Code install. Am I missing something or is this functionality beyond the scope of this tool?

Comment: EDIT: I had to run `Syncing: Download Settings` 2x to get the Extensions to download. No biggie, just a heads up. Thanks for the killer tool!

Comment: I have mixed feelings posting my settings to a (semi-)public Gist. Some extensions store sensitive data (such as database logins, SFTP logins) in their settings. Would it be hard to redirect storage to a "local" file instead, synchronized by an external tool like Syncthing or Resilio Sync?

Comment: @korkman Exporting to local storage is not supported yet, but it could be better to support the file synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

I did this on my Mac by copying VS Code's `settings.json` to my iCloud drive for automatic backup, and then creating a symbolic link.

1. Copy `settings.json` from [VS code settings directory](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` to your backup location
2. Backup the old `settings.json` by renaming to `settings-old.json`
3. In the terminal, `cd` to VS code setting dir: `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/`
4. Create the symlink to your backed up file using command `ln -sf path/to/backup/settings.json settings.json`. Since I backed mine up to iCloud and renamed the file to `vscode.settings.json`, my command looked like this: `ln -sf ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/vscode.settings.json settings.json`
5. Check that you can open up user preferences in VS Code

To use the backup on a different Mac, just repeat steps 2-5.

I also did this for [extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions)...

```
cd ~/.vscode/
mkdir ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/vscode/
cp -a extensions ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/vscode
mv extensions extensions-old
ln -sf ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/vscode/extensions extensions
```

Comment: @frankhommers It looks like this can be replicated using the Window's symlink command: [`mklink`](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/). You can use DropBox, OneDrive, or another cloud service instead of iCloud drive

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing it would be to soft link your files, which can also be stored in a repository on GitHub. For example, on Mac OS let's say you have a directory called `~/dev/dotfiles/vscode`. Let's say there are two files in there called `settings.json` and `keybindings.json`. You could soft link these files with:

```
ln -s ~/dev/dotfiles/vscode/keybindings.json ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/keybindings.json
ln -s ~/dev/dotfiles/vscode/settings.json ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
```

If you are using Windows or Linux the path to the respective settings directories can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Answer (score 4):

I place my `settings.json` in a configuration file that I sync with git (though Dropbox would also work) and use a Python script to symlink it to the correct location for each platform so updating it from the settings menu syncs across my machines. Creating symlinks requires admin privileges on Windows.

```
import os
import platform

# Find the settings file in the same directory as this script
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
VS_SETTINGS_SRC_PATH = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'settings.json')

# https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH = os.path.expandvars(r"%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json")
elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
    VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH = os.path.expandvars(r"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json")
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    raise NotImplementedError()
else:
    raise NotImplementedError()

# On Windows, there might be a symlink pointing to a different file
# Always remove symlinks
if os.path.islink(VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH):
    os.remove(VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH)

choice = input('symlink %r -> %r ? (y/n) ' % (VS_SETTINGS_SRC_PATH, VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH))
if choice == 'y':
    os.symlink(VS_SETTINGS_SRC_PATH, VS_SETTINGS_DST_PATH)
    print('Done')
else:
    print('aborted')
```

Answer (score 3):

**User Settings**

There is currently no automatic synchronization for user settings available in Visual Studio Code. 
On Windows the user settings are located in `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`. You could save a copy of that file on OneDrive or Dropbox and move it on all your machines to the user settings folder. But this still includes manual steps on each machine every time you change the configuration.

You can suggest an automatic synchronization of settings here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

**Workspace Settings**

Add the `.vscode` folder of your workspace to the version control system (Git/SVN etc). When you checkout the code from the repository you will automatically get the VS Code workspace settings.

Comment: Thanks for replying but you've misunderstood the question. I'm asking about user settings, not project settings. I've added some clarification to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I improved the answer

Answer (score -8):

Use workspace-settings instead of user-settings.

Comment: Not a constructive suggestion as workspace settings do not sync across project or systems.

Comment: Giving @ColacX the benefit of the doubt, I'm assuming what was meant was that if you use workspace-settings, you can save them in git/svn/etc, which _does_ in fact sync them in a sense.