# How can I export settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How is it possible to export all Visual Studio Code settings and plugins and import them to another machine?

Comment: For reference, Code offers a [portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) so you can just move the installation folder.

Comment: There is currently an open feature request issue that appears to be in the design proposal phase. I am going to wait for this official support. You can subscribe to the issue and get notifications on the progress. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2743#issuecomment-560116420

Answer (score 241, accepted):

There is an extension for Visual Studio Code, called *[Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)*.

It synchronises your settings by gist (Gist by GitHub). It works the same as the Atom.io extension called *settings-sync*.

**UPDATE:**

This feature is now built into VS Code, it is worth switching to the official feature.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035356/2029818)

> You can now sync all your settings across devices with VSCode's built-in Settings Sync. It's found under Code > Preferences > Turn on Settings Sync...

Comment: Is this really an export? I would export an export workflow to generate a file or set of files containing settings in some directory - not rely on third party services and underlying setup.

Comment: Of course you can do it. The external package isn't necessary, but it keeps your packages sync between more VSC instances (by instances I mean multiple instalations)

Comment: That extension did not work for me at all.  It just gives "Error not found" when you try to import the settings to another computer, and I followed the instructions to the letter.  Be careful if you decide to use this.

Comment: @dcp this is due to invalid gist id, you can open issue to let the author know

Comment: can I copy settings without running the old version, just having the access to the disk where it was installed?

Comment: Just to point out the next reply is worth looking. More upvotes than the chosen one! :)

Comment: vscode now has settings sync built-in but just a PSA on this answer -- do not use this. your settings may contain secrets and gist is **public**.

Comment: As Cory mentioned this is built-in now. See Ole August Støle's answer below...

Comment: Now I'm also using build in feature :)  I've added update to my response. Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 516):

With the current version of Visual Studio Code as of this writing (1.22.1), [you can find your settings in](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

- `~/.config/Code/User` on Linux
- `%APPDATA%\Code\User` (`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`) on Windows
- `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/` on Mac OS X

The files are `settings.json` and `keybindings.json`. Simply copy them to the target machine.

[Your extensions are in](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_where-are-extensions-installed):

- `~/.vscode/extensions` on Linux and Mac OS X
- `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` (`C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions`) on Windows (i.e., essentially the same place as on Linux and Mac OS X)

Alternately, just go to the *Extensions*, show installed extensions, and install those on your target installation. For me, copying the extensions worked just fine, but it may be extension-specific, particularly if moving between platforms, depending on what the extension does.

Comment: @zerohedge I expect the workspace specific settings are in the `.workspace` file, or in the `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: Great answer! I'd create 2 folders: (1)  ~/.vscode/extensions and (2) ~/.vscode/settings. Then I'd create symlinks to the paths in your answer according to the specific OS. Once it's done, I just put my ~/ folder under version control. Like this, I keep my dotfiles and vscode config all in one repo.

Comment: On Mac Monestary with vscode insiders, there is no `~/Library/Application Support/Code` folder

Comment: There's also `tasks.json` and `snippets/` under `~/.config/Code/User`.

Comment: Somewhat outdated look at @Rohan Khude answer

Answer (score 60):

Similar to the [answer given by Big Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39750624) you can do the following:

```
$ code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension
```

This will list out your extensions with the command to install them so you can just copy and paste the entire output into your other machine:

Example:

```
code --install-extension EditorConfig.EditorConfig
code --install-extension aaron-bond.better-comments
code --install-extension christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
code --install-extension christian-kohler.path-intellisense
code --install-extension CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
```

It is taken from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-vs-code-extension-list).

Note: Make sure you have added VS Code to your path beforehand.  On mac you can do the following:

1. Launch Visual Studio Code
2. Open the *Command Palette* (<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and type 'shell command' to find the
   Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

Comment: For PS users: something like `code --list-extensions | %{"code --install-extension $($_)"}`

Comment: For a plain cmd use `code --list-extensions>extlist` on a source PC and `for /f %f in (extlist) do code --install-extension %f` on a target PC. Where `extlist` is a file with extensions' names.

Comment: For the rest of us (Linux and Windows), it is Shift + Ctrl + P for the Command Palette.

Answer (score 53):

You can now synchronise all your settings across devices with Visual Studio Code's built-in *Settings Sync*. It's found under menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Turn on Settings Sync...*

Read more about it in the official documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync).

Comment: I don't have this setting on linux.

Comment: try to update VS code. ,  its there .   Im using ubuntu 18.04 and setting sync feature is inbuild here .

Comment: In my case I found the option in `Code → Preferences → Turn on Settings Sync`

Answer (score 49):

For posterity, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list/37189011#37189011) mentions,

> in the latest release of Visual Studio Code (May 2016) it is now possible to list
> the installed extension in the command line

```
code --list-extensions
```

On Mac, execute something like:

```
"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app//Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" --list-extensions
```

To install, use:

```
--install-extension <ext> //see 'code --help'
```

Answer (score 27):

VS Code provides 2 options to take care your settings. One is import/Export and other is Sync settings with github profile.

**Follow below steps to Export VS code settings**

1. Search for 'Profiles: Export' in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
   [image]
2. Select 'what to export' and confirm by clicking on 'OK'
   [image]
3. Name your export -

[image]

4. Select Local file which will download the file

[image]

To import, choose 'Profiles: Import' from Command Palette

Comment: Thanks, this should be the first answers in 2023! Worked perfectly fine and took about 2min.

Answer (score 16):

Your user settings are in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User`.

If you're not concerned about synchronising and it's a one-time thing, you can just copy the files `keybindings.json` and `settings.json` to the corresponding folder on your new machine.

Your extensions are in the `~/.vscode` folder. Most extensions aren't using any native bindings and they should be working properly when copied over.
You can manually reinstall those who do not.

Answer (score 5):

I'm preferred my own way to synchronize all Visual Studio Code extensions between laptops, using `.dotfiles` and small script to perform updates automatically. This way helps me every time when I want to install all extensions I have without any single mouse activity in Visual Studio Code after installing (via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))).

So I just write each new added extension to *.txt* file stored at my `.dotfiles` folder. After that I pull *master* branch on another laptop to get up-to-date file with all extensions.

Using the script, which Big Rich had written before, with one more change, I can totally synchronise all extensions almost automatically.

#### Script

```sh
cat dart-extensions.txt | xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

And also there is one more way to automate that process. Here you can add a script which looks up a Visual Studio Code extension in realtime and each time when you take a diff between the `code --list-extensions` command and your *.txt* file in `.dotfiles`, you can easily update your file and push it to your remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a Python script for exporting Visual Studio Code settings into a single ZIP file:

https://gist.github.com/wonderbeyond/661c686b64cb0cabb77a43b49b16b26e

You can upload the ZIP file to external storage.

```
$ vsc-settings.py export
Exporting vsc settings:
created a temporary dump dir /tmp/tmpf88wo142
generating extensions list
copying /home/wonder/.config/Code/User/settings.json
copying /home/wonder/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
copying /home/wonder/.config/Code/User/projects.json
copying /home/wonder/.config/Code/User/snippets
  adding: snippets/ (stored 0%)
  adding: snippets/go.json (deflated 56%)
  adding: projects.json (deflated 67%)
  adding: extensions.txt (deflated 40%)
  adding: keybindings.json (deflated 81%)
  adding: settings.json (deflated 59%)
VSC settings exported into /home/wonder/vsc-settings-2019-02-25-171337.zip

$ unzip -l /home/wonder/vsc-settings-2019-02-25-171337.zip
Archive:  /home/wonder/vsc-settings-2019-02-25-171337.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-02-25 17:13   snippets/
      942  2019-02-25 17:13   snippets/go.json
      519  2019-02-25 17:13   projects.json
      471  2019-02-25 17:13   extensions.txt
     2429  2019-02-25 17:13   keybindings.json
     2224  2019-02-25 17:13   settings.json
---------                     -------
     6585                     6 files
```

---

PS: You may implement the `vsc-settings.py import` subcommand for me.

Answer (score 2):

Enable [Portable Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)

Portable Mode instructs Visual Studio Code to store all its configuration and plugins in a specific directory (called data/ in Windows and Linux and code-portable-data in macOS).

At any time you could copy the data directory and copy it on another installation.

Answer (score 2):

This is my syncing configuration repo for VSCodium (for **Linux** only). If you use VSCode, just replace the `codium` with `code` and the syncing will be fine.

https://github.com/vanvuvuong/codium_configuration

Comment: Link `https://github.com/vanvuvuong/codium_configuration` is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Often there are questions about the Java settings in Visual Studio Code. This is a big question and can involve advanced user knowledge to accomplish.  But there is simple way to get the existing Java settings from Visual Studio Code and copy these setting for use on another PC.  This post is using recent versions of Visual Studio Code and [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) in mid-December 2020.

There are several screen shots (below) that accompany this post which should provide enough information for the visual learners.

First things first, open Visual Studio Code and either open an existing Java folder-file or create a new Java file in Visual Studio Code.  Then look at the lower right corner of Visual Studio Code (on the blue command bar).  The Visual Studio Code should be displaying an icon showing the version of the *[Java Standard Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition)* (Java SE) being used.  The version being on this PC today is JavaSE-15.  `(link 1)`

Click on that icon (`JAVASE-15`) which then opens a new window named "`java.configuration.runtimes`". There should be two tabs below this name: `User` and `Workspace`.  Below these tabs is a link named, "`Edit in settings.json`".  Click on that link. *(Link 2)*

Two `json` files should then open: `Default settings` and `settings.json`. This post only focuses on the "`settings.json`" file.

The `settings.json` file shows various settings used for coding different programming languages (Python, [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), and Java).  Near the bottom of the `settings.json` file shows the settings this User uses in Visual Studio Code for programming Java.

These Java settings are the settings that can be "backed up" - meaning these settings get copied and pasted to another PC for creating a Java programming environment similar to the Java programming environment on this PC. *(Link 3)*

[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk2Jq.png)

[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nbm8.png)

[Link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqJNA.png)

Comment: Don't rely on the position in the file; it can change. As far as I'm aware, position is not even significant at all to the configuration system.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, "export **all** Visual Studio Code settings and plugins". If this is the answer to a more specific question, you could post it separately; see [self-answer](/help/self-answer) in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

For those looking for an export option for Visual Studio (not Code), use Tools menu, select "Export selected environment settings"

Comment: This question is about VSC, not VS.

Comment: @wjandrea That's why I said that excplicitly if somebody is looking for the equivalent in VS.