# How to export settings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

As posted here [How can I export settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368889/how-can-i-export-settings), everyone insists on using Settings Sync, which would be fine if I wasn't forced to use GitHub by the plugin (which is explicitly denied on my computer).  Is there any way to either do this manually, or to redirect the plugin to use an alternative git repo for this purpose?

Comment: 1. Opening a new question instead of asking in comments is always better. 2. You can request account retrieval if you lost access to the previous account. 3. Question should never contain your life story. Please stick to technical writing and do not include any noise.

Comment: VScode provides option to import/export settings - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75281411/4635388

Answer (score 4):

For Windows what you need to do is,

1. copy `keybindings.json`, `settings.json` files and `snippets` folder from
   `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`.
2. and copy `extensions` folders from
   `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app` to your new machine at the same locations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly you can. You basically need to

1. copy `keybindings.json`, `settings.json` files and `snippets` folder from `/home/<user>/.config/Code/User`
2. and copy `extensions` folders from `/home/<user>/.vscode/`
   to your new machine at the same locations.

Please note - the above locations are for `Ubuntu`. Check what are these for your operating systems.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706409/5164382