# Moving VSC extensions to new computer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Due to a recent computer issue I had to purchase a new computer. Fortunately I was able to install the old SSD drive in the new computer as a 2nd SSD device (D:). I installed VS Code on the C: drive. So the questions... Is there a folder/file on the D: drive that I can move to the C: drive so that all of the installed extensions and setting will be available?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync You should migrate before moving the actual hardware, and that's the only supported approach. In current state, there isn't a reliable way to move (you can try all hacks over the internet, but no guarantee that they help).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368889/how-can-i-export-settings)

Answer (score 1):

under `C:\Users\{Username}\.vscode` you find a folder called `extensions`, this contains all your extensions

copy the folder and paste it in the second device

Comment: Copy/Paste worked fine. But, there are no Installed extensions showing in the extensions panel.

Comment: try to copy settings.json from C:\Users\ {Username} \AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Comment: The AppData folder does not exists on the D:\Users\(UserName)\ directory.

Comment: Daa... found the folder, copy/pasted the setting.json file to the C: drive. Opened vscode... nothing. Restarted system... nothing. Moved the contents of the Extensions folder to the C: drive... nothing. Did move the snippets.json file to the C: drive. That worked fine.

Thanks for your help!