# Sharing settings on Visual Studio Code installations

Tags: visual-studio-code

I casually use VS Code at both work and home. Is there any easy way to share settings, themes, shortcuts, snippets, extensions, etc. between multiple installations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to sync my Visual Studio Code settings between instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392127/is-there-any-way-to-sync-my-visual-studio-code-settings-between-instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [Settings Sync extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) to sync my settings.

If you don't want an extension, you can manually copy the settings files from `...AppData\Roaming\Code\User\`