# VS-Studio Code copy and export profile

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, visual-studio-addins

I have my profile setup the way I like in VS-Studio Code.

Is it possible to copy the profile and/or sign into Microsoft or similar repository to retrieve what plugins and behaviors I like when going from computer-to-computer?

Like with Google Chrome, if I sign into Google Chrome on a new computer/profile, I get all of the add-ins and such that I like.

Comment: A few ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392127/is-there-any-way-to-sync-my-visual-studio-code-settings-between-instances plus two extensions noted therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export settings of Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368889/how-to-export-settings-of-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Check also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48774503/2275011

Comment: This is great!  I think this will work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Easily, no. VS Code doesn't currently have a full profile backup feature. Anything you do to back it up will need to be done manually.

Copying the `.json` config files for VS Code that live in the `AppData/Roaming/Code/User` folder on Windows (I don't know what it is on Mac) is a good start for saving the keybindings, settings, and code snippets.

I don't know if this works, but you can also try copying the entire `AppData/Roaming/Code/User` folder to the other machine.

If you want to preserve the extensions, you can copy the entire `.vscode` folder in the user directory (Windows) to the other machine.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use Setting Sync to have the same setup on different machines.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

But, also on 1.67 version was added as a preview a basic and limited option to import and export profiles.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_settings-profile