# Portable user settings and extensions in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to export -> import settings, extensions and other configuration from visual studio code? I am working on multiple computers, and would like to have the same VS Code environment setup everywhere. Is there a way accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an extension that does exactly this called Settings Sync (aka/old name: Visual Studio Code Settings Sync)

You can find it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

It uses your github account token and gist and syncs:

```
- VSCode Extensions Settings
- Keybinding File
- Workspaces
- Launch File
- Settings File 
- Snippets Folder
```