# Is there any way to automatically update VSCode settings on close via Settings Sync?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to update the settings on github via Settings Sync when I close VSCode, is there any way to do it?

Comment: While not exactly what you are looking for there is a "sync.autoUpload": true, setting which will upload your settings whenever the files change.

Comment: @Mark, hi, it seems your idea solve this issue, could you please add an answer with it when you have free time? That will benefits for others to easier search this information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Settings Sync [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) does have an option to upload the settings whenever thesettings are changed:

> Toggle Auto-Upload on change
>
> Auto-upload is disabled by default. When the settings are changed and
>   saved this feature will automatically start the upload process and
>   save the settings online.
>
> Select Command "Sync : Advanced Options > Toggle Auto-Upload on
>   Settings Change" command to Turn ON / OFF the auto-upload.

Or set

```
"sync.autoUpload": true,
```

`false` is the default.

-------  UPDATE  -----------

Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#settings-sync as a preview feature in v1.43. Or see my fuller answer here:

[Is there any way to sync my Visual Studio Code settings between instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392127/is-there-any-way-to-sync-my-visual-studio-code-settings-between-instances/60456591#60456591)

> You can now sign in with your GitHub account to synchronize your VS
>   Code preferences.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#settings-sync