# What's the recommended way to track VS Code configuration with version control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

At the moment, I reproduce my VS Code configuration on any new machine by tracking the folders `~/.vscode/` and `~/.config/Code/User/` with version control. So when I install an OS on a new machine, I install VS Code, then I link those locations to the actual folder that are in my git repository that I've cloned onto the machine (automated with a script).

It works, but I'm not sure that this is the best way:

- It tracks all the VS Code package sources that are in `~/.vscode/extensions`, which can be a lot of large-size changes committed into my repo.

  - For example, the file
    `.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.26.2/debugAdapters/lldb/lib/liblldb.3.8.0.dylib` alone
    is 50MB, and my last commit to update my VS Code config was 299.17 MiB!
- `~/.config/Code/User/` contains a lot of stuff too, and probably some of it is junk that doesn't need to be tracked, and VS Code doesn't ship any `.gitignore` files in these config folders (maybe they imply for us to track everything?).

What's the recommended way to track my VS Code configuration and replicate it on any machine?

> (P.S., if any VS Code devs read this, this is all super simple with Atom, and it *does* ship with `.gitignore` files which makes it obvious they thought about people tracking their Atom configuration, and `.gitignore` prevents them from tracking stuff they don't need to.)
>
> (P.S. 2, Here's a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88811) for the VS Code team to officially support this.)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using "[Sync setting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)" for my vscode, it is basically download the extension, set up and forget. I found this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/settings-sync-with-vs-code-c3d4f126989) helpful. Is this what you are looking for?

**Edit:**
Even more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357313/6596203) from the extension creator.